# Load a responsive web app in an android app without using a Webview(Slow On Most Devices, Chrome Custom Tabs ,Browser Intent or TWA?

Tags: java, android

Have tried loading a responsive web app on webview but it was very slow on most devices,I then tried Chrom Custom Tabs,Trusted Web Activity and Browser Intent but you cannot hide the top tool bar for both.I tried implemeting libraries like geckoview and crosswalk without success .

I expected it to be work like webview woul but a little faster like in Chrome Custom Tabs